# Where does the tradition of bowing after a performance come from?

Tags: history, performance-practice

Why do we bow after a performance? Where does this tradition come from? For how long has performers been doing this?

Maybe there is some sort of interesting anecdote about this.

Comment: This article suggests it was from the days of royal patronage as a bow to the royalty after (and maybe originally before) a performance, since the performers were literally in the presence of the monarch: http://www.dancespirit.com/uncategorized/take_a_bow/

Comment: That sounds like an answer Todd

Comment: Well, one column on a dance web site is not exactly a reputable historical source, so it's more of a supposition than an answer.

Comment: I had prepared a lovely answer complete with anecdotes to the effect that the tradition evolved from artists dodging the rotten tomatoes and other fruit thrown by a particularly keen audience ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Bowing was originally a gesture (a movement of the body) which showed
>   deep respect for someone."

After a performance, bowing is basically a sign of respect to the audience, for listening and potentially clapping.

More about bowing [here](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowing).

Answer (score 1):

In some areas of the world, the musicians acknowledge applause by applauding back. Bowing is another method (which lends itself to a rehearsed bow from the entire cast.)

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.